# How to update and insert data in postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have the below situation. I receive data from a datasource in CSV format every two weeks. I upload that to a postgres dB. I need to ensure the following

1. data in postgres should not be deleted
2. any updates in CSV need to be carried over without adding new rows
3. any new data marked by uinque ID Needs to be added

In other words the diff between the data set needs to be appended to postgres

In today's implementation I am using node-postgres to stream the data to postgres

I dont know how to implement the updates

Any ideas ? Ideally if there is a way to create a temp table stream the new data and do a diff between the old and temp table will be good.

Answer (score 0):

If the CSV has a unique ID already, and you're using PostgreSQL 9.5+, then you can use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ...`. Otherwise you could create a plpgsql stored procedure with parameters (either individual values or a single ROW parameter), that does

```
UPDATE table SET
  value = param_value
  ...
WHERE ID = param_id;

IF NOT found THEN
  INSERT INTO table (ID, value, ...)
  VALUES (param_id, param_value, ...);
END IF;
```

And execute that function for each row on the CSV. You can first import the CSV into a temporary table and do

```
SELECT the_above_function(f.id, f.value, ...)
FROM csv_temp_table f;
```